# how to find the max values of groupby pandas with the column name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Actually I want to find the maximum values of the teachers_prefix with the teacher's prefix (for eg: in this case mrs, and the value which is 639471

Input can be found [image: here]

Comment: based out of the image , you are already able to fetch the `max` value , what exactly do u need or stuck at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [pd.Series.idxmax()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html). This returns the index of the column/series where you get the max value.

```
#grouped_df[[grouped_df.idxmax()]] #If series

grouped_df.loc[grouped_df.idxmax()] #If dataFrame
```

```
teacher_prefix
mrs  639471
Name: sum, dtype: int64
```

---

If you want one or more than one rows based on top n largest values -

```
grouped_df.nlargest(2, 'sum')
```

Comment: This worked for me grouped_df.nlargest(1,grouped_df)

Comment: I dont think this would be the optimal way to do it. You are using the nlargest with n=1. The purpose of the function is to get the top n rows in a dataset. Have you tried idxmax() as i suggested?

Comment: Is your goal to get the complete row? or you just want the prefix?

Comment: Yes I tried but it would just display the id but i needed the id with its value. so i used nlargest

Comment: oh ok, i think it was not very clear from your question. I have updated my code. Do check if that works.

Comment: KeyError: "['mrs'] not in index"

Comment: see now? does it work? with double brackets?

Comment: Oh wait, your ouptut table is a dataframe or a series?? i think its a dataframe because only then this wont work.

Comment: ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,2)

Comment: see now. i used loc to pull the rows.

Comment: Yes, its a dataframe

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot brother. It completely works

Comment: glad to help, I am also adding syntax for nlargest as well.

Comment: Hey can you help me in another question please. See my profile